# Efficient (constant space or sublinear space) way to find out the cardinality of ( (A intersect B) union C ) intersect D )?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, hyperloglog

I am currently using hyperloglog to estimate the cardinality of sets (# of unique items)

Its quite trivial to calculate the cardinality for the union of 2 sets and the cardinality for the intersection of 2 sets (`|A intersect B| = |A| + |B| - |A union B|`)

But I couldn't quite find a way to chain the operators of union and intersection together (note: the method of only allow calculating the cardinality not hyperloglog of intersection, that is, it is possible to get a new hyperloglog via `A union B` but not `A intersect B`).

Are there alternative algorithms that can estimate the cardinality of the result of chained union and intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Dogged use of Boolean algebra will do the trick, though you may not be happy with the quality if selectivity is low.

```
|((A n B) u C) n D| =
|(A n B) u C| + |D| - |(A n B) u C u D| =
|(A u C) n (B u C)| + |D| - |(A u C u D) n (B u C u D)| =
|A u C| + |B u C| - |A u B u C| + |D| - |A u C u D| - |B u C u D| + |A u B u C u D|
```

You should probably double check my math.